# How to delete wrong link from ~/.bashrc?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, aliases

After

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

I always get

> bash: /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh: No such file or directory

when I work with the terminal.  How can I fix this?

Comment: vi ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile, find the line in error and delete it. Or comment it out. No?

Comment: There is no direct link to "/usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh" in ~/.bashrc.

Comment: What does `~/.bashrc` have to do with the question? This sounds like you just have a broken package installed and its removal script is borked. This doesn't appear to be a programming problem at all (if it is, you need to put a lot more information and the scripts you are writing in your .deb file) and would be better asking on Superuser of a Stack Exchange about Ubuntu.

Comment: According to [this](https://superuser.com/a/896642) answer, you should also check /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper

Comment: Going through the logs of `PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE}:$LINENO+' bash -x -l -i` to see which code actually *invokes* that during shell startup (whether it's in `.bashrc` or elsewhere) would be a place to start in tracking down the chain of events (and determining whether `.bashrc` actually has anything at all to do with it or not).

Answer (score 1):

I fix it with "sudo apt-get purge virtualenvwrapper"
according to

https://superuser.com/questions/893448/bash-shell-error-no-such-file-or-directory/896642#896642